# InputMismatchException when scanning from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-io

I am writing a program that takes information from an input file (First and last name, hourly rate, and hours worked) calculates the net pay and writes it to a different file. The file wages.txt has the following:

```
First Name, Last Name, Hourly pay, Hours Worked
Bruce, Wayne, 7.25, 40
John, Jones, 8.50, 45
Clark, Kent, 7.25, 42
```

The output should be:

```
Last Name, First Name, Total Pay
Wayne, Bruce, 290
Jones, John, 361.25
Kent, Clark, 297.25
```

The overtime rate is half of the hourly rate. The rate is a double and the hours worked is an int. In my tests the output format line gets wrote to the file, and the exception is thrown as the program gathers the information for calculating pay.

```
static void wages(){
    //input file
    String file_name = "wages.txt";
    File input_file = new File(file_name);
    Scanner in_file = null;

    //This is the format line that will be wrote to the output file
    String out_format_line = "Last Name, First Name, Total Amount";

    //output file
    String file2_name = "out.txt";
    File output_file = new File(file2_name);
    PrintWriter out_file = null;

    try{
        out_file = new PrintWriter(output_file);
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: The output file does not exist");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try{
        in_file = new Scanner(input_file);
        in_file.useDelimiter("[,\n]\\\\s");
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: The input file does not exist");
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try{
        //This line is useless and is removed with this variable
        String in_format_line = in_file.nextLine();
        //writes format line for output file
        out_file.print(out_format_line);
        while(in_file.hasNextLine()){
            //gathers relavent materials for calulating pay
            String first_name = in_file.next();
            String last_name = in_file.next();
            double rate = in_file.nextDouble();
            double over_rate = rate/2;
            int hours = in_file.nextInt();

            //calculates net pay with overtime
            if(hours > 40){
                int overtime = hours - 40;

                double norm_pay = 40*rate;
                double over_pay = overtime * over_rate;

                double net_pay = norm_pay + over_pay;

                out_file.print(last_name);
                out_file.print(", ");
                out_file.print(first_name);
                out_file.print(", ");
                out_file.println(net_pay);
            }
            //calculates net pay without overtime
            else{
                double net_pay = hours*rate;

                out_file.print(last_name);
                out_file.print(", ");
                out_file.print(first_name);
                out_file.print(", ");
                out_file.println(net_pay);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException ex){
        System.out.println("Error: File format is incorrect");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        in_file.close();
        out_file.close();
    }
}
```

}

When ex.printStackTrace() is ran the console says:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
at guided.exercise.pkg4.GuidedExercise4.wages(GuidedExercise4.java:120)
at guided.exercise.pkg4.GuidedExercise4.main(GuidedExercise4.java:18)
```

Comment: Please include the stacktrace anytime your problem involves an exception. Don't simply exit the program from inside the `catch` block. Instead, do `ex.printStackTrace()` to have information about the error printed to the console.

Comment: @VinceEmigh I've never used that before so if I've used it incorrectly please let me know

Comment: No. `InputMismatchException` when *reading input* from something.

Comment: You missed a `catch`, which i believe may be the actual problematic code. You then have to run it, so the stack trace appears in the console. Copy & paste that here.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Code has been updated

Comment: Gotta pay a closer attention to instructions given to you, it's a bad habit to skim over help. "*You then have to run it, so the stack trace appears in the console. Copy & paste that here.*" It'll tell you the exact line number that the exception occurred on, so it'll help if you could also point out in your code where that line is.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Apologies, I've been on this for a while and my brain is fried. The results have been added.

Comment: It seems you set the delimiter to include `,` but not whitespace. When the scanner tokenizes `Wayne, Bruce, 290`, the token `290` will have a space behind it. Add whitespace to the delimiter so it doesn't affect the tokens.

Comment: @VinceEmigh The code in the post has been updated with your correction. If I added it correctly it's now throwing an `NoSuchElementException` I changed the delimiter to `in_file.useDelimiter("[,\n]\\\\s");` The exception is being thrown at line 119 which is `String last_name = in_file.next();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the delimiter. Thanks to Vince Emigh's suggestions he showed me that I had it only set for newline characters and commas. So when the program was scanning the input file it was including the whitespace behind the `290` token thus throwing the InputMistmatchException. By changing `in_file.useDelimiter("[,\n]");` to `in_file.useDelimiter("[,\n]\\\\s");` it corrected the problem I was having.